# Text in table is defaced for no apparent reason

Tags: tables, formatting, lists

I made this table (now is modified to reproduce the problem described on Edit 1):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[spanish,mexico]{babel} 

\usepackage{arabtex} 
\usepackage{utf8} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{10pt} %separación columnas
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2} % separación filas
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\begin{document}
\vocalize %usar diacriticos
\setarab
\setcode{utf8}

\noindent Si anteponemos \RL{ا}, \RL{مَا}, o \RL{مَنْ}  a \RL{هَذَا} , se convierte en una pregunta: 
\begin{itemize}
\item Frase afirmativa: \RL{هَذَا بَيْتٌ} (Esto es una casa)
\item Frase interrogatoria 1: \RL{اَهَذَا بَيْتٌ؟} (¿Es esto es una casa?)
\item Frase interrogatoria 2: \RL{مَنْ هَذَا؟} (¿Quién es este?)
\item Frase interrogatoria 3: \RL{مَا هَذَا؟} (¿Qué es esto?)
\end{itemize}
\bigskip

\begin{Large}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{cc|c c|}
\cline{1-4}
\multicolumn{4}{ |c| }{\begin{LARGE}\RL{تَحْلِيلْ الْجُمَلْ }\end{LARGE}} \\ \cline{1-4}
\multicolumn{1}{ |c }{\multirow{4}{*}{\rotatebox{-270}{\RL{مُذَّكَرُُ مُفْرَدْ}}} } &
\multicolumn{1}{ |c }{\RL{الْمُشَرُ اِلَيْهِ}} &  \RL{اسْمُ الاِشَارَة} & \RL{الْجُمْلَة}       \\ \cline{2-4}
\multicolumn{1}{ |c  }{}                        &
\multicolumn{1}{ |c }{\RL{نَجْمٌ}} &  \RL{ذَلِكَ} & \RL{ذَلِكَ نَجْمٌ}      \\ \cline{2-4}
\multicolumn{1}{ |c  }{}                        &
\multicolumn{1}{ |c }{\RL{مَسْجِدٌ، بَيْتٌ }} & \RL{هَذَا، ذَالِكَ} & \RL{هَذَا مَسْجِدٌ وذَلِكَ بَيْتٌ}      \\ \cline{2-4}
\multicolumn{1}{ |c  }{}                        &
\multicolumn{1}{ |c }{\RL{حِصَانٌ، حِمَارٌ }} & \RL{هَذَا، ذَالِكَ} & \RL{هَذَا حِصَانٌ وذَلِكَ حِمَارٌ}      \\ \cline{1-4}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{Large}

\end{document}
```

Which looks like this:

[image: good table]

...but only when it is in its own .tex file, alone. When I put it within the original file with other tables and normal text it looks like this:

[image: bad table]

And I don't know why. TeXmaker does not send me any error and the rest of the tables above and below this one look perfect.

---

**Edit 1** I discovered that the issue is this part of the original file:

```
\begin{itemize}
\item Frase afirmativa: \RL{هَذَا بَيْتٌ} (Esto es una casa)
\item Frase interrogatoria 1: \RL{اَهَذَا بَيْتٌ؟} (¿Es esto es una casa?)
\item Frase interrogatoria 2: \RL{مَنْ هَذَا؟} (¿Quién es este?)
\item Frase interrogatoria 3: \RL{مَا هَذَا؟} (¿Qué es esto?)
\end{itemize}
```

If I delete this part from the code, or if I put my table before this part, the table looks good. But I don't really see why this list is a problem, since there are other lists before and after this one and all the other tables look good.

In fact, if I erase *this particular* `itemize` environment, while leaving the text, the problem is gone. Is this a glitch, a bug? **I still don't get any error while compiling**, not even a warning.

---

**Edit 2** I modified the first code so that the problem can be reproduced. If you erase the `itemize` environment or if you put the table before it, the problem is solved. Now I get a warning, which is caused by using the `Large` and `LARGE` environments, when I delete those the warning is gone but the main problem remains... in a smaller fontsize.

Comment: There is no `Large` environment. What happens if you delete `\begin{Large}` and `\end{Large}` and instead put `\Large` immediately after `\begin{center}`?

Comment: Can you please provide a minimal *complete* document allowing us to reproduce the problem? I ask you about this complete version since when I add the list to your code with the table, I can't reproduce the problem mentioned.

Comment: @IanThompson Thanks for the comment. I did as you told and nothing changed.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Thanks for pointing that out. I modified the first code.

Comment: I've provided an answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I traced down the problem to the `\RL` commands in the sentence

```
\noindent Si anteponemos \RL{ا}, \RL{مَا}, o \RL{مَنْ}  a \RL{هَذَا} , se convierte en una pregunta:
```

Grouping those commands, as in

```
\noindent Si anteponemos {\RL{ا}}, {\RL{مَا}}, o {\RL{مَنْ}}  a {\RL{هَذَا}} , se convierte en una pregunta:
```

solves the problem:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[spanish,mexico]{babel} 

\usepackage{arabtex} 
\usepackage{utf8} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{10pt} %separación columnas
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2} % separación filas
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\begin{document}
\vocalize %usar diacriticos
\setarab
\setcode{utf8}

\noindent Si anteponemos {\RL{ا}}, {\RL{مَا}}, o {\RL{مَنْ}}  a {\RL{هَذَا}} , se convierte en una pregunta: 
\begin{itemize}
\item Frase afirmativa: \RL{هَذَا بَيْتٌ} (Esto es una casa)
\item Frase interrogatoria 1: \RL{اَهَذَا بَيْتٌ؟} (¿Es esto es una casa?)
\item Frase interrogatoria 2: \RL{مَنْ هَذَا؟} (¿Quién es este?)
\item Frase interrogatoria 3: \RL{مَا هَذَا؟} (¿Qué es esto?)
\end{itemize}
\bigskip

\begin{center}
\Large
\begin{tabular}{cc|c c|}
\cline{1-4}
\multicolumn{4}{ |c| }{\RL{تَحْلِيلْ الْجُمَلْ }} \\ \cline{1-4}
\multicolumn{1}{ |c }{\multirow{4}{*}{\rotatebox{-270}{\RL{مُذَّكَرُُ مُفْرَدْ}}} } &
\multicolumn{1}{ |c }{\RL{الْمُشَرُ اِلَيْهِ}} &  \RL{اسْمُ الاِشَارَة} & \RL{الْجُمْلَة}       \\ \cline{2-4}
\multicolumn{1}{ |c  }{}                        &
\multicolumn{1}{ |c }{\RL{نَجْمٌ}} &  \RL{ذَلِكَ} & \RL{ذَلِكَ نَجْمٌ}      \\ \cline{2-4}
\multicolumn{1}{ |c  }{}                        &
\multicolumn{1}{ |c }{\RL{مَسْجِدٌ، بَيْتٌ }} & \RL{هَذَا، ذَالِكَ} & \RL{هَذَا مَسْجِدٌ وذَلِكَ بَيْتٌ}      \\ \cline{2-4}
\multicolumn{1}{ |c  }{}                        &
\multicolumn{1}{ |c }{\RL{حِصَانٌ، حِمَارٌ }} & \RL{هَذَا، ذَالِكَ} & \RL{هَذَا حِصَانٌ وذَلِكَ حِمَارٌ}      \\ \cline{1-4}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice that `\Large` and the other font size switches are commands without arguments and not environments; their proper use is

```
{\Large text}
```

the braces are needed just if explicit grouping is required to keep the effect local.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation! So, do you recommend to always put braces to enclose the \RL command? How come the rest of the text that is not coded like that did not interfered with the other tables? I don't understand the criteria to identify the problem in the future (sorry I'm new with LaTeX).

Comment: @lumiso To be honest, I don't know why my answer works, because it's really unexpected and explicit grouping shouldn't be required; I even asked in the chat room (see transcript [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/16546663#16546663)) to see of someone could explain what was going one here, but as you see from egreg's answer, the mystery remains.

Comment: @lumiso Now Heiko Oberdiek has provided a cause for the experienced behaviour; you can see it [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/16547434#16547434). Later I will add some comments about this as an edit to my answer.